# indentation syntax

Tags: python-3.x

tengo un error en este codigo, acerca de una mal indentacion, es el siguiente:

```
while True:
 print('Who are you?')
name = input()
if name != 'Joe':
continue
  print('Hello, Joe. What is the password? (It is a fish.)')
password = input()
if password == 'swordfish':
break
  print('Access granted.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando estes trabajando con Python, preferiblemente usa un editor de código como Jupyter o Spyder por el motivo que estos editores te dan la identación automática.

Por otro lado cuando estes dentro de una sentencia produra dar la indentación con usando `TAB`, asimismo identifica bien los niveles de cada sentencia para poder asignar el mensaje adecuado.

**Código Python**

```
while True:
  print('Who are you?')
  name = input()
  if name != 'Joe':
    continue
  print('Hello, Joe. What is the password? (It is a fish.)')
  password = input()
  if password == 'swordfish':
    break
print('Access granted.')
```